# How to create a horizontal line of three circles

Tags: html, css

**What I'm trying to create**

Using HTML5 and CSS3 only, a horizontal row of three circles, each sitting on top of a different image, containing another image and one word of text.

**What I have tried**

I have tried to create this by just adding divs within divs and specifying heights and widths, but this has not worked. I sense I'm over-complicating something quite simple, or forgetting something very obvious. What is the simplest way of doing this?

**A note**
Go easy on me! I've been trying to self-learn for only 2 months.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="circlewrapper">
   <div class="sector" id="read">
      <img src="images/test1.jpg" class="image1" height="165" width="165" />
      <div class="round" id="reading">
         <img src="images/book.jpg" class="image2" height="20" width="20" />
         <p id="readread">Read</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sector" id="listen">
     <img src="images/test2.jpg" class="image1" height="165" width="165" />
     <div class="round" id="listening">
         <img src="images/book.jpg" class="image2" height="20" width="20" />
         <p id="listlist">Listen</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sector" id="watch">
     <img src="images/test3.jpg" class="image1" height="165" width="165" />
     <div class="round" id="watching">
         <img src="images/book.jpg" class="image2" height="20" width="20" />
         <p id="watchwatch">Watch</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.circlewrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 270px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;}
.sector {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 8px;
  display: inline;}
.round {
  height: 165px;
  width: 165px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 165px;
  -moz-border-radius: 165px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 165px;
  z-index: 10;}
p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;}
.image1 {
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index: 5;}
.image2 {
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `.sector` `float: left;`. It worked for me.